# RestTemplate upload image as MultipartFile with Content-Type image/jpg

Tags: post, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to upload an image (MultipartFile) using RestTemplate to a server URL.
Sending request from postman works with `Content-Type: image/jpg` and an image sent as Binary File from Body.

Method implementation in SpringBoot:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadImage(MultipartFile file) {
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter());

    LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Object> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    params.add("file", new FileSystemResource(file));
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(params, httpHeaders);

    return restTemplate.exchange(UPLOAD_URL, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap] and content type [image/jpeg]
```

Upload works with Content-Type `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` but REST Service that I use only accepts `image/jpg` as HTTP Content-Type.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Your remote service accept `image/jpg` so you should stream byte instead of multi-part:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");

Resource res = new InputStreamResource(file.getInputStream());

HttpEntity<Resource> entity = new HttpEntity<>(res, headers);
template.exchange(UPLOAD_URL, HttpMethod.POST, entity , String.class);
```

The `RestTemplate` has `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` which streams your multi-part to the service for you.

Comment: I'm now getting this error `No HttpMessageConverter for org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource and content type "image/jpeg"`

Comment: @Ron.Basco Change `InputStreamResource` declaration to `Resource`. See my edit

Comment: @Ron.Basco Did you register `ResourceHttpMessageConverter`? `restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());`

Comment: I found the issue. Is it because the rest template I am using. I have static params in the URL which the rest template is reencoding.